# PhpStorm code auto completion for PHP const nested array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, phpstorm

I want some nested JSON like var for some configuration.

In JavaScript, the obj,  PhpStorm can show candidate properties:

```
const ABC = {
  A1: 123,
  A2: [
    B1: 33,
    B2: 44
  ]
}

// after type each dot `.`, PhpStorm can show candidate properties
console.log(ABC.A2.B1)
```

But not working for PHP, PhpStorm can only show candidate for the first level of the array, not for deeper array, and doesn't show error tips if index not exist:

```
<?php

class TT
{
    const  ABC = [
        'A1' => 123,
        'A2' => [
            'B1' => 123,
            'B2' => 5566
        ]
    ];

    public function f1()
    {
        // PhpStorm can only show candidate for the first level of the array
        // not for deeper array
        echo self::ABC['A2']['B1'];

        // not show error tips for not exist index
        echo self::ABC['A12345']['B1'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @SahilGulati , I wrote it wrong, what I want to express is `echo self::ABC['A2']['B1'];`

Comment: Try this  https://eval.in/791266, This will work in PHP7 or above

Comment: @SahilGulati , My nested array may be three level deep, and more then 10 items for each level, because I want to use all the items of this const nested array in many other places.

Comment: You can try this, https://eval.in/791278, If it is help ful..

Answer (score 1):

ATM code completion works for 1st level array keys only.

Accordingly to devs such tracking and completion (even for 1st level array keys) is a bit resource-intensive operation.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6845 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.